# SSIS - Imported string fields from Oracle are converted into wrong/bad charaters

Tags: character-encoding, collation, ssis, data-migration

Using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) I am migration a table from Oracle (11g) to SQL Server 2008 R2. The table's fields are int, string (data type Unicode strings [DT_WSTR]) and blob type converted to image data type.

SQL Server's collation is "Latin1_General_100_CI_AS".

The workflow is pretty straighforward:

1) An ADO NET element gathers data from the Oracle source.
2) A script component maps the inout column with the output columns with some data conversion
3) A SQL Server destination element stores the records to the target database

During the data migration (in total just 20'000 records) some string fields are stored with asian characters, while other that have same value are moved properly. 
As example:

```
  ID             CODE              USRNAME           DOCNAME
  ---------------------------------------------------------
  120            B-0000001         OAS2491          Help.pdf
  121            D-0000465         Charlie          Doc1.pdf
  122            D-0000465         Charlie          Doc2.pdf
  123            殹榁鴀ځᡑ䇜쿫       Ɫ灿풑뾧껳쮏⽏�    Doc3.pdf
  124            D-0000465         Alpha            Doc2.pdf
```

As first thing I thought to some special characters in the source table, but I checked the affected records and they are exactle the same as in the other rows properly migrated.
Row with ID 123 has the same values as row 122, that is displayed fine.

**On Oracle**:     
CODE is a VARCHAR2 (15 Byte)               
USRNAME is a VARCHAR2 (36 Byte)

**On SQL Server**: 
CODE is a nvarchar(15)               
USRNAME is a nvarchar(36)

Why some rows are migrated with wrong characters when others not, even if the content is the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue by replacing the "SQL Server destination" component with an "OLE DB Destination" element.

With the lattest all rows are properly imported without any wrong characters.